# mapDispatchToProps props null in jest test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have just started my first react job (yay!) and am *attempting* to write unit tests using **jest**. i am having an issue with mapDispatchToProps in my test.

please note, the test passes, but it is throwing the following error message:

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `testDispatch` is marked as required in `TestJest`, but its value is `undefined` in TestJest

error seems to be test related to the test as it is not thrown when running the page in the web browser. also, mapStateToProps works fine, included to show it works.

using enzyme/shallow in order not to interact with the `<Child/>` component.

**testJest.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Child from './Child'

export class TestJest extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>ABC - <Child /></div>);
  }
}

TestJest.propTypes = {
  testDispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  testState: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string)
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    testState: state.utilization.pets    // ['dog','cat']
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    testDispatch: () => dispatch({'a' : 'abc'})
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TestJest);
```

**testJest-test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { TestJest } from '../Components/testJest';
import TestJestSub2 from '../Components/TestJestSub2';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('TESTJEST', () => {
  it('matches snapshot', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<TestJest />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Comment: It's because you call `<TestJest />` in your test without `testDispatch` nor `testState` (you set them as required in your propTypes) ?

Comment: @soywod - thank you for your reply. i do not yet know enough about react/jest to respond fully to your comment, so let me add two things which may be relevant:  1) the testState requirement passes, it is only testDispatch that fails, and 2) this is how the component gets called in the app and does not generate any error messages.  thanks again for taking the time to reply.
this may also address your concern: testState and testDispatch are injected into <TestJest /> via connect().

Answer (score 2):

You can pass empty function to `TestJest` as `testDispatch` prop:

```
it('matches snapshot', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<TestJest testDispatch={() => {}} />);
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

or pass jest mock function:

```
it('matches snapshot', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<TestJest testDispatch={jest.fn()} />);
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

if you want to check if testDispatch was called (`expect(wrapper.instance().props.testDispatch).toBeCalled();`)

Comment: thanks @Mikhail, your example does eliminate the error messages! this solution does require that i call `<TestJest \>` in the test with attributes that are not required in the actual code, so that is a bit of a bummer, but it does rid me of those pesky messages!  

i will be glad to mark this as a solution if an answer is not presented that maintains code/test consistency.

thank you so much for your time.  bill